# Change font of a line

Tags: fonts

I'm thinking of making a UI which has different font size/color for different lines.
Can I change the font of a particular line, like the color and size?

Org-mode can do this for headlines, so I suppose this is possible, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Please do not post the same question to both StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Please choose one and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: Sorry I have removed one.